# SVG drawing not exactly the same circle with the same path but different color

Tags: svg, graphics, cairo, antialiasing

I am using pycairo, below is the full snippet:

```
from math import pi
from cairo import PDFSurface, Context, Matrix
WIDTH = 6 * 72
HEIGHT = 4 * 72
s = PDFSurface('example1.pdf', WIDTH, HEIGHT)
c = Context(s)
# Draw a circle
c.save()
c.set_line_width(0)
for i in range(1000): 
    c.arc(1 * 72, 3 * 72, 0.5 * 72, 0, 2 * pi)
    c.set_source_rgb(1.0, 0, 0)
    c.fill()
    c.arc(1 * 72, 3 * 72, 0.5 * 72, 0, 2 * pi)
    c.set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    c.fill()
s.finish()
```

I expected the resulted pdf to be blank. But there's a red-circle as you can see. I know it's caused by anti-aliasing, and the same question was asked long time ago here:
[Two exactly same SVG paths not drawn exactly the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002698/two-exactly-same-svg-paths-not-drawn-exactly-the-same-way)
But the answer didn't explain how the anti-aliasing caused that effect.

It will be appreciated if somebody could tell me *how* it happened.

Thanks!

Comment: Some good info on how shortcuts in SVG rendering causes this (see **joojaa**'s comments or **Yakk**'s answer in particular): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you want to draw half a pixel red: You do `cairo_rectangle(cr, 42, 42, 0.5, 1);` to get a rectangle which is half a pixel wide. Then you set a red source color and draw this (on a white background).

What would be the expected result?

Well, half the pixel is white (`(1, 1, 1)`), half of it is red (`(1, 0, 0)`). So the logical thing to do is to mix red and white, resulting in a color like `(1, 0.5, 0.5)`.

Next, you want to draw the same "half a pixel" in white. The information that the "left half" of the pixel is red and the "right half" is white, was not saved anywhere. So, the pixel has just this "reddish-white mix". So, again, some mixing is required: half `(1, 0.5, 0.5)` and half `(1, 1, 1)` is `(1, 0.75, 0.75)`, or a mix of 1/4th red and 3/4th white.

So, even though we filled the very same geometry first with red and then with white, the red is still partly visible.

What does this have to do with anti-aliasing? A circle does not fit perfectly into the circle grid. So, near the edge you get some pixels that are only partially inside the circle. Anti-aliasing means that something similar to what I explained above is done: The background color and the circle's fill color are mixed. Thus, this mixing means that some of the first color stays visible after the circle was "erased" again.